# TypeORM onDelete setting for related entities when soft delete

Tags: typeorm

I want to confirm something that I see.

`softDelete` will not trigger anything on the `{ onDelete: 'xxx' }`. Correct?

If I am correct, then if I want something to happen on the related entities when I `softDelete` ( ex. `Set Null`), I have to wire it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onUpdate` since `softDelete` is an `UPDATE` operation, it updates the `deleted_at` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.